# Error in I2C Communication Between Arduino and Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, i2c, communication, raspberrypi

The code below sends data to Raspberry Pi every 20 millisecond. The code works fine but sometimes python throws an error. Why this is happening? Should I give more time between `writeData`?

**Error:**

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rpi-I2C.py", line 33, in
> <module>
> writeData("360")   File "rpi-I2C.py", line 12, in writeData
> bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,0x00,byteValue) OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

**Python code:**

```
import smbus
import time
# for RPI version 1, use bus = smbus.SMBus(0)
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x04

#http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-python/i2c-programming-in-python/using-the-i2c-interface-2
def writeData(value):
    byteValue = StringToBytes(value)    
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,0x00,byteValue)
    #first byte is 0=command byte.. just is.
    return -1


def StringToBytes(val):
        retVal = []
        for c in val:
                retVal.append(ord(c))
        return retVal

while True:
    print("sending test")
    writeData("left")   
    time.sleep(0.02)

    #print('Sending OPEN-00-00');
    writeData("right")
    time.sleep(0.02)

    #print('Sending WIN-12-200');
    writeData("360")
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

**Arduino code**:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04

volatile boolean receiveFlag = false;
char temp[32];
String command;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  // define callbacks for i2c communication    
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);    
  Serial.begin(115200);    
  Serial.println("Ready!");    
}

void loop() {    
  if (receiveFlag == true) {    
    Serial.println(temp);    
    receiveFlag = false;    
  }    
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany) {    
  for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {          
    temp[i] = Wire.read();    
    temp[i + 1] = '\0';  //add null after ea. char    
  }
    
  //RPi first byte is cmd byte so shift everything to the left 1 pos so temp contains our string    
  for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i)    
    temp[i] = temp[i + 1];    
    receiveFlag = true;    
  }
```

Comment: Slowing it down a bit would be the first thing I'd try, e.g., crank it up to .5sec. If that fixes it you'll know it's a timing issue. You could also speed up the Arduino side by temporarily removing the `Serial.println` because it could just be the Arduino can't keep up since it's serial-ing while the host is still blasting I2C data. (Only do one change at a time, obviously).

Comment: Changing sleep time to 0.5Sec works but I want to send data every 20ms. Is there any way to do this? What causes the problem exactly? Is Arduino reading data slower than expected?

Comment: Serial output is relatively slow.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an active level translator for the Arduino and the Pi. This I would expect with a passive (resistor) level translator. A simple trick is to transmit with 2 stop bits and receive with 1. This gives you a free bit time for each character.

Answer (score 1):

A RPI uses 3.3v logic while an arduino uses 5v logic you can use a logic converter but by now it's probly to late and maybe your arduino or RPI is broken (***Sorry!***)